# "Get-Service –ComputerName myserver" not working on one of my Virtual Machine in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I m trying to run powershell script from my machine to get the Services status from a remote machine. 
The command I am using in my script is given below
"`Get-Service –ComputerName myserver`".
My remote machine is a virtual Machine.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I am getting the following error:Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'myserver'. This operation might require other privileges.
At line:3 char:8
+ $Res = Get-Service -ComputerName myserver
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.
However, I don't know why this command not working directly from source to Remote server but I found an alternative. Use given function on source machine and pass server name as param value and it will return all services with their status.

`function GetAllservices { 
param(
        $ComputerName
    )
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName 
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {get-service}
Remove-PSSession -Session $sess}`